# Having a string for NSDatePicker?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, cocoa-bindings, xamarin.mac

I want the NSDatePicker cell to display "No date selected" when a user checks a checkbox - How can I do it, given that NSDatePicker accepts only NSDate as its value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place a label with the desired text in the same spot in the UI and tie the hidden property of the date picker to the checkbox backing BOOL and tie the hidden property of the label to the same BOOL with the NOT modifier.

Comment: Is there an alternative without adding a new control ?